# System() call for Null session connection with space

Tags: c++, qt, cmd, qprocess, quoting

I'm struggling with successfully executing this command on Qt creator

```
net use \\192.168.15.111\Admin$ /user:Administrator Password
```

using system() like so:

```
system("net use \\192.168.15.111\Admin$ /user:Administrator Password");
```

but i keep getting this compiler warning and it does not compile

```
..\qprocess\mainwindow.cpp:25:10: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\A'
   system("net use \\192.168.15.111\Admin$ /user:Administrator Password");
          ^
```

as well as with QProcess like this:

```
  QProcess process;
  process.start("net use \\192.168.15.111\Admin$ /user:Administrator Password");
  process.waitForReadyRead();
  ui->textEdit->setText(process.readAll());
  process.waitForFinished();
```

I get the same compiler warning.
I searched everywhere for a unified guide on properly quoting paths(if this is even considered a "path") but I couldn't find anything (a link for something like that would be good, as I'm a pretty inexperienced programmer).

I also don't know how to approach this problem accordingly, on what should I orientate myself?, on using classes like QDir or QFileInfo? (but I kept thinking that this isn't actually a file path but the syntax of the command).
Or should I look at things like QString.Split()

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: thanks for replying, what does the R stand for? 
I get a warning 'R' was not declared in this scope

Comment: use `system("net use \\\\192.168.15.111\\Admin$ /user:Administrator Password")`

Comment: solved my problem! thank you :D